# MSE function returning NaNs in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following columns. A sample here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'product_id' : [20,20,20,20,20,22,22,22,22,22], 'date' : ['2020-06','2020-07','2020-08','2020-09',
                   '2020-10','2020-06','2020-07','2020-08','2020-09',
                   '2020-10'],'real': [1.2,3,4,5,1,1.5,2.9,5,6,1], 'pred': [1.3,4,4,5.1,1.2,1.5,3,6,5,1.5]})
```

And I want to calculate the MSE:

```
for game_id in df['product_id'].unique():
    pred_g = df.query(f"product_id == '{game_id}'")
    print(game_id, " MAE = ", mse(pred_g["real"], pred_g["pred"]))
```

I created a mse function directly:

```
def mse(actual, predicted):
    actual = np.array(actual)
    predicted = np.array(predicted)
    differences = np.subtract(actual, predicted)
    squared_differences = np.square(differences)
    return squared_differences.mean()
```

And it is returning only NaN values for each product_id:

[image]

If I try to calculate it with the Sklearn function, then I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0,)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

I have checked both x and y variables and both of them have the same shape and are not empty.

What can it be happening? I am quite confunsed.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output? Also which degrees of freedom do you want to use? Your formula is **NOT** computing the [MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error), but a simple square of the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html) per groups:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
s = (df.groupby('product_id')
      .apply(lambda x: mean_squared_error(x['real'], x['pred'], squared=False)))
    
print (s)
product_id
20    0.460435
22    0.672309
dtype: float64
```

Or count it manually:

```
s = df['pred'].sub(df['real']).pow(2).groupby(df['product_id']).mean().pow(0.5)
    
print (s)
product_id
20    0.460435
22    0.672309
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you wan use [`GroupBy.var`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.var.html):

```
df['real'].sub(df['pred']).groupby(df['product_id']).var(ddof=0)
```

output:

```
product_id
20    0.1336
22    0.4376
dtype: float64
```

Manual computation:

```
s = df['real'].sub(df['pred'])
s.groupby(df['product_id']).apply(lambda x: x.sub(x.mean()).pow(2).mean())
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I am not getting any error.

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'product_id' : [20,20,20,20,20,22,22,22,22,22], 'date' : ['2020-06','2020-07','2020-08','2020-09',
                   '2020-10','2020-06','2020-07','2020-08','2020-09',
                   '2020-10'],'real': [1.2,3,4,5,1,1.5,2.9,5,6,1], 'pred': [1.3,4,4,5.1,1.2,1.5,3,6,5,1.5]})
 
def mse(actual, predicted):
    actual = np.array(actual)
    predicted = np.array(predicted)
    differences = np.subtract(actual, predicted)
    squared_differences = np.square(differences)
    return squared_differences.mean()
    
for game_id in df['product_id'].unique():
    pred_g = df.query(f"product_id == '{game_id}'")
    print(game_id, " MAE = ", mse(pred_g["real"], pred_g["pred"]))
```

Output:

```
20  MAE =  0.21200000000000002
22  MAE =  0.45199999999999996
```

Comment: Note that the formula used by OP is erroneous, the MSE is the mean of the squares of the **differences of the errors to the mean of the errors**. The used formula is simply getting the square of the errors here, which is incorrect.